# How to tell what "[Event Procedure]" refers to in VBA code?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm just reading some VBA code which sets event handlers on controls like this:

```
mfrmForm.OnUnload = "[Event Procedure]"
```

How am I supposed to tell which function/method is being assigned, and where its implementation is located?

Answer (score 1):

The code is in the class module of the form, i.e. `Form_mfrmForm`.

The procedure is called:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
```

Comment: Hmm. Then, what is the use of dynamically assigning an event handler? If `mfrmForm.onUnload` can **only** be set to `Form_mfrmForm.FormUnload`, why set it at all in VBA code?

Comment: I have no idea. It is rather unusual to do that. It may be completely superfluous. A remote possibility: under some conditions the setting is `=SomeFunction()` and under other conditions it is set to `=[Event Procedure]`. But that would be quite hackish. @AlexD

Comment: It may be a relic. If you e.g. cut and paste a control from a form to a tab control on the form, the `[Event Procedure]` setting for event handlers gets lost. Maybe someone wanted to make sure this never happens again. Or so. @AlexD

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my understanding the `[Event Procedure]` declaration for the `OnUnload` property is a flag for Access to know there is a VBA coded event handler defined in the code module for that object. Since you are also able to specify a `macro` or `expression` the `[Event Procedure]` flag is used for VBA coded events.

Lets say you create the handler in the code module for `Form_Unload` event manually, and the `OnUnload` property is left blank. Since the `[Event Procedure]` declaration is not defined, the event will not be triggered when the form is unloaded.